# How to replace missing white space with NA in R?

Tags: r, replace

I am working on genetic data and I have a huge output file (tab delimited text file), where in some columns I have missing values. These are left as white space.

I want to change the white space with NA or (.). How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 3):

Have you actually tried to read your file in? Under `?read.table`, the argument `na.strings` it states:

> **na.strings**
>   *a character vector of strings which are to be interpreted
>   as NA values. Blank fields are also considered to be missing values in
>   logical, integer, numeric and complex fields.*

So, I'm guessing (in lieu of a reproducible example)...

```
read.table("C:/myfile.txt , sep = "\t")
```

If you have blank space in columns with `character` data, you can explicitly set `na.strings = ""` which *should* make R consider all white space as `NA`...

```
read.table("C:/myfile.txt , sep = "\t" , na.strings = "" )
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But the problem is that I want to save a new file where I can actually see NA, when I open it with any other program besides R.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a data frame called `df` and a column called `v1`, you can recode as missing any strings that are entirely white space via a combination of `replace()` and `grepl()`:

```
df$v1 <- replace(df$v1, grepl("^\\s*$", df$v1) == TRUE, NA)
```

As described by @Cath [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35726243/4342901), the `grepl` portion searches the string for "0 or more" (*) spaces (\s) between the beginning (^) and end ($) of a string. If it the string matches those criteria, it's deemed `TRUE`, otherwise `FALSE`.

Nested within the `replace` function, then, R will recode any observation in `df$v1` that matches those criteria (i.e. that is `TRUE`) as missing (i.e. `NA`).

Comment: Here is an alternative method for all columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76815200/r-dplyr-replace-strings-with-only-spaces-for-all-columns