# Replacing "white spaces" in a column with "null" in R

Tags: r

I am working on data cleaning techniques in R

I have a data.frame as shown below:

```
    names marks
1  dinesh    20
2            30
3 achyuth    40
4            NA
5  mourya    50
6            NA
7    hima    50
```

Here in the above result,

1. I need to replace the "empty space (or) white space" in the names column with "null".
2. And I need to replace the `NA` in the marks column with "0".

Could any one suggest how to get this done?

Comment: NULL is not a value that can live as an element of a vector in a data frame. So do you mean the text string "NULL", or maybe ""?

Comment: yes I want to replace with text string "NULL"

Comment: Check out the related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144427/how-to-replace-missing-white-space-with-na-in-r

Comment: or if you want to do it to many columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76815200/r-dplyr-replace-strings-with-only-spaces-for-all-columns