# Checking if a string contains all blankspace in R

Tags: r, string, whitespace

Im looking to see if a string contains only blank space. The string could be

```
"  "
```

or

```
"           "
```

or

```
"              "
```

etc...

I want to do this so I can change values in a data frame to NA, because my goal is to fix/clean messed up data.

Thank you

Answer (score 15):

You can try with `grepl`:

```
grepl("^\\s*$", your_string)
```

`"^\\s*$"` asks for 0 or more (`*`) spaces (`\\s`) between beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of string.

**Examples**

```
grepl("^\\s*$", " ")
#[1] TRUE
grepl("^\\s*$", "")
#[1] TRUE
grepl("^\\s*$", "    ")
#[1] TRUE
grepl("^\\s*$", " ab")
[1] FALSE
```

*NB: you can also just use a space instead of `\\s` in the regex (`"^\\s*$"`).*

Comment: a better regex would be 
`grepl("\\s+", your_string, perl = True)` the + forces it to match 1 more spaces.

Comment: @Seekheart it is actually why I prefered `*` so it also checks for the empty string, I thought the OP might also want empty strings to be spotted (and further modified as `NA`) (btw, yours wouldn't work without specifying beginning and end of string, you don't need perl option for that and TRUE must be written in uppercase ;-) )

Answer (score 12):

Without regex, you could use

```
which(nchar(trimws(vec))==0)
```

The function `trimws()` removes trailing and leading whitespace characters from a string. Hence, if after the use of `trimws` the length of the string (determined by `nchar()`) is not zero, the string contains at least one non-whitespace character.

Example:

```
vec <- c(" ", "", "   "," a  ", "             ", "b")
which(nchar(trimws(vec))==0)
#[1] 1 2 3 5
```

The entries 1, 2, 3, and 5 of the vector `vec` are either empty or contain only whitespace characters.

---

As suggested by Richard Scriven, the same result can be obtained without calling `nchar()`, by simply using `trimws(vec)==""` (or `which(trimws(vec)=="")`, depending on the desired output: the former results in a vector of booleans, the latter in the index numbers of the blank/empty entries).